# How to do an integration test for a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing

**TLDR:** Should you test a compiled JAR or is it enough to write a `@Test` method to run the main class?

I have a Spring Boot service that integrates with several other services.

Currently, in order to test the integration between the services I'm running the compiled JAR in sort of a staging environment while simulating the other services.

Is there a benefit of running the compiled JAR over running a unit test that runs the main application and mocks (e.g. using Mockito) the other services?

Or maybe, do I need both of these capabilities?

Comment: Hey, your question is very broad, opinion based and hard to answer without knowing your project. Also, everyone has its own opinion about what an integration test is, what a unit test is etc. I suggest you to do the research by yourself and comeback with a specific problem rather than a broad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you'll want both. This is a great guide on testing strategies for microservices
https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/

The unit tests that test only a specific piece of your application with other parts of the internal application mocked. These can run as part of your CI/CD pipelines.

You'll also want to run integration tests in your codebase using mocks for external systems. Those can run as part of your pipelines and use the test annotation you mentioned. These will ensure that your application functions correctly as long as the contracts to the external systems are correct.

Then you may want to do some runtime smoke testing as well against a running application using external tools that invoke your APIs.